# Show multiple term references as ID in one row

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I've got a view of nodes, displayed as fields. As each node may have references to multiple terms/tags, I would like to show all these tags.

When I use field "term_node_tid", then I get the multiple values properly displayed in one row separated by commas. But instead of the readable term, I need the term-IDs.

So I set up another field using "tid", but now only the ID of the first term is shown. There's no multiple value field setting, where I could tweak things. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps using [template_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/8.2.x) you might be able to get a hold of all those id's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Change field Formatter

If you're showing the actual Content field you can change the `Formatter`. Instead of using `Label` use **Entity ID** under `Formatter`.

This will output Term IDs instead of term names, and all the Multi-valued settings will apply the same way as for the names output.

### Rewrite results with TID replacement token

Another way or changing the field output in D8 views (if the Formatter option isn't available for example) is to use the `Rewrite results > Override the output of this field with custom text` and enter the token for the TID in there. You can look up the correct token pattern under `Replacement patterns` below the `Text` area.

That is also how you would get the TID to display instead of the name if you use the field **Content: All taxonomy terms**.

Comment: neither the formatter option is available, nor rewriting like {{ tid }} reveals all values … I can't believe this standard task isn't a no-brainer. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Can you post more information and screesnhots about your configuration? For example the field settings for `term_node_tid`, multivalue and rewrite results?

Comment: It is unbelievable: in order to make screenshots I built the view from scratch and the options for multi-value fields and ID-formatter just appeared. Realy don't know what happened before.

Comment: It's a well-known issue in programming that sometimes software starts behaving erratically with no reason :) Or maybe it's a case of "It’s harder to read code than to write it". Do you still have the original views? You can compare it to the new one and find out where the "ghost" is.

Comment: unfortunately, I deleted the old view…